# Quantum physics notation in statistical physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, notation, magnetic-moment

Studying statistical physics, in particular studying paramagnets and ferromagnets, I found some quantum mechanical formulas that I don't understand how to interpret. I don't understand if they are equations between operators, eigenvalues or mean values (or something else that I don't know). Can anyone tell me how to interpret these quantum equations (i write examples of them below)? To be clear, I am not asking for an explanation of physical phenomena but an explanation of the notation, which to me looks like a mix of eigenvalue operators and expectation values together.

**Example about paramagnets**

magnetic moment of each single ion
$$\vec \mu=g \mu_B \vec J$$
where g is the Landé g-factor
$$g=1+\frac {j(j+1)+s(s+1)-l(l+1)}{2j(j+1)}$$
It follow that, if there is a magnetic field, the interaction energy is
$$H=-\vec \mu \cdot \vec B=-g \mu_B B m_j$$
where the possible values of $m_j$ are $(-j,-j+1,...0,...,j-1,j)$

**Example about ferromagnets**

Hamiltonian of the system in the presence of $\vec B$
$$H=-g \mu_B \vec B \cdot \sum \vec S_i - J \sum \vec S_i \cdot \vec S_j $$

Comment: They are indeed operators. But it's understood that they will be evaluated on wave functions with definite values of angular momentum (when this can be done and depending on cases, i.e. angular vs total angular momentum). Then you can replace the "operators" by their eigenvalues (when applied to the proper spherical armonics).

Comment: interesting, why should we use only eigenstates of angular momentum?

Comment: Because we know beforehand that those are conserved quantities, i.e. they commute with the Hamiltonian. Then you can diagonalize the full Hamiltonian using eigenvectors of angular momentum (and or spin or total angular momentum, depending on what quantity is actually conserved).

Comment: PS i agree, in most books that part is actually presented in a confusing way.

Comment: Ok, it seems to me a possible explanation. However, the user J.G. below gives a different answer and it also seems a possible explanation

Comment: If you think about it, it's actually the same answer. The expectation value of an operator on an eigenfunction is the eigenvalue. But you can also say that the value of an operator on all the functions with definite angular momentum, is that eigenvalue.

Comment: J.G. answer can be confusing because it gives the impression that you obtain a number (the expectation value). But, (depending on where you are in the calculation) you actually still have an operator (proportional to the identity). Usually you still have to do some work to completely diagonalize the Hamiltonian. This is particularly evident in the example of the ferromagnet.

Comment: but if the equations is about expectation values it is valid for all the possible states while if it's about operators it's valid only for eigenstates right?

Comment: Frankly, it's really not an expectation value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135655/discussion-between-lcv-and-simobartz).

Comment: ok, i text you there

Comment: i asked a specific [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/712557/hamiltonian-eigenstates-in-weiss-heisenberg-model)  based on your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: I equate expectation values below to emphasize which constants can be moved outside bra-kets. To get the operator equations from such these expectation equations follow, just mentally delete the bra-kets. Nothing here contradicts any other users' insights, given which operators are mutually diagonalizable with the Hamiltonian.

In this case it would be more helpful to write${}^\dagger$ $$\left\langle\hat{H}\right\rangle=\left\langle-\hat{\vec{\mu}}\cdot\vec{B}\right\rangle=-\mu_BB\langle gm_j\rangle.$$The first set of angle brackets were likely dropped because an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian is assumed. Why someone woud drop the second set will hopefully become clear from the footnote below.

${}^\dagger$ We probably put $\vec{B}$ in "by hand", making it classical rather than quantized, which is why I didn't give it an operator hat. The second expression can be rewritten can then be rewritten as e.g. $-\left\langle\hat{\vec{\mu}}\right\rangle\cdot\vec{B}$. The resulting empirical law, by which the eigenenergy is a dot product, allows us to identify $\vec{\mu}$ with its mean.

Edit to address new ferromagnet example: this should be clarified as$$\left\langle\hat{H}\right\rangle=-\mu_B\vec{B}\cdot\sum_i\left\langle g\hat{\vec{S}}_i\right\rangle-\sum_{ij}\left\langle\hat{J}\hat{\vec{S}}_i\cdot\hat{\vec{S}}_j\right\rangle.$$

Comment: i don't understand how it's possible that the expectation value depends on g. Isn't g well defined only for eigenvectors?

Comment: @SimoBartz See edit.

Comment: ok now i understand. I edited my question to add another example, can you explain also that?

Comment: @SimoBartz Done.

Comment: Ok this answer is useful, however, the user Icv in the comments above gives a different answer to the question. They both seems possible explanation to me but probably only one is correct (i don't know which one)

Comment: @SimoBartz Apologies for some confusion; see my new note.

Comment: I beg your pardon but mentally deleting bra-kets is not a well defined (mathematical) procedure :). The correct way is that of looking at an operator in a certain subspace. The resulting operator is called a restriction of, say $X$, to a certain subspace say $V$.

Comment: @lcv What I meant was "I'm not writing both $X=Y$ and $\langle X\rangle=\langle Y\rangle$; I'm writing the latter, but the former is correct on a suitable subspace, and from that the latter follows; therefore, you can tell what the former is by removing some characters, even though the inference won't run in that direction".

Comment: What you are doing is effectively trying to define the restriction of an operator in a certain subspace. Look at Robert Israel answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056674/what-is-the-restriction-operator-on-an-eigenspace#:~:text=Given%20a%20linear%20operator%20T,%CE%B1%20times%20the%20identity%20operator.)