# Hamiltonian eigenstates in Weiss-Heisenberg model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, ferromagnetism

Reading about paramagnetism and ferromagnetism i've seen this formula:
$$ \mu=g \mu_B J$$
where $g$ is the Landé g-factor
$$g=1+\frac {j(j+1)+s(s+1)-l(l+1)}{2j(j+1)}$$
From the answer to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/704503/quantum-physics-notation-in-statistical-physics/704507?noredirect=1#comment1576427_704507) i understood that this formula should be interpreted as an equation between operators acting on the same eigenstate, namely:

$$\hat \mu |j,s,l,m_j \rangle=g \mu_b \hat J |j,s,l,m_j \rangle$$

It follows that the same formula can be also interpreted as an equation between the eigenvalues of $|j,s,l,m_j\rangle$, namely (measuring $J$ in units of $\bar \hbar$):

$$ \mu=g \mu_B m_j$$

Now, if the part above is correct i suppose that the Hamiltonian formula in the Weiss-Heisenberg model should be interpreted analogously but unfortunately i don't understand which are the eigenstates that should be considered

$$H=-g \mu_B \vec B \cdot \sum \vec S_i - J \sum \vec S_i \cdot \vec S_j $$

So, if the interpretation i'm giving to the formula is correct can you tell me the eigenstates to which it refers? If you think the interpretation is wrong feel free to explain how it should be interpreted.

Comment: Wait. The meaning or interpretation depends on the context. In the other question regarding Hydrogen atom, there was a particular operator. Since one knows that certain quantum number are conserved one *can* look at that operator in the subspace spanned by those quantum numbers. In math strictly speaking one is looking at the restriction of an operator in a certain subspace. In the Heisenberg model the only degrees of freedoms are the local spins. $g$ there has the value given by experiments

Comment: Which hydrogen atom? in the other question i wrote the same formulas. About the quantum number, it seems that you are speaking about the projection of the operator into the subspace spanned by a not complete set of conserved states? Can you give me an example?  Finally, about the Heisenberg model, do you mean that the state is $\chi (s_1,...,s_n)$ where the $s_i$ are the spin components of each particle on z axis? Sorry for bothering you but i'm a autodidact in physics and i need clarifications also for obvious things

Comment: Re first question: yes. Although it's not called a projection but a restriction. Re second question also yes

Comment: The conserved quantum numbers eigenstates should be a complete set, why are you speaking of subset? can you give me an example?

Comment: Let's consider the Heisenberg model in external field (as in this or in the other question). You can assume the field is along $z$. So you have a term $h M$ where $M=\sum_i S_i^z$. From the theory of angular momentum the eigenvalues of $M$ are of the form $m=-N S, -(N-1)S,\ldots NS$ where $N,S$ are the number of particles and local spin respectively. But each eigenvalue is largely degenerate. In each sector of fixed total magnetization that term equal $hm I$ where $I$ is the identity operator in that space.

Comment: Since also $S^2$ is conserved you can use the quantum numbers $|m,l\rangle$ but each subspace with $m,l$ fixed has still a big degeneracy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i appreciate. Unfortunately i don't understand the last part: "In each sector of fixed total magnetization that term equal $hmI$ where $I$ is the identity operator in that space". What do you mean with "...each sector of fixed total magnetization..."? I noticed that if i consider an eigenstates of $\hat M$ than $h \hat M |m \rangle=h m I |m\rangle$. About the last comment, just to be sure $m$ is the $z$ component quantum number and $l$ the total angular moment quantum number?

Comment: Yes $m,l$ are the $z$ and total angular momentum quantum numbers. You can build their respective eigenvectors $|m,l\rangle$ but these are degenerate, so we should rather write $|m,l,i\rangle$ where $i$ counts the degeneracy. Leaving out $l$ for simplicity, what is the degeneracy of the sector $M=m$? (I.e. how many linearly independent vectors can you find that have quantum number $m$ for a system of $N$ particles?